# GCC builtin functions - 2003 vs 2019 behaviour

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, built-in

At page 14 of the book "***Introduction to GCC***" by *Brian Gough*, the author wants to show a linker error due to not supplying gcc with the `libm` library, where the code for the function `sqrt` resides:

```
$ gcc -Wall calc.c -o calc
/tmp/ccbR6Ojm.o: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/ccbR6Ojm.o(.text+0x19): undefined reference to ‘sqrt’
```

The file `calc.c` (where the function`sqrt` is invoked) is this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    double x = sqrt (2.0);
    printf ("The square root of 2.0 is %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This book is from 2003. 
On my current Ubuntu Linux 18, I can't reproduce the link error: it links and works, printing the correct result:

```
$ ./calc
1.414214
```

I found with `ldd calc` that the `libm.so` shared library is not invoked at runtime. Nor of course is the static library `libm.a` involved here.
So how does gcc deal with the function `sqrt`? I found that in this case it uses the `sqrt` ***GCC built-in function***. 
Its code gets inserted in the `calc.o` object file at compile time. So no "undefined reference" error.

**First question**: this the whole story or am I missing something?

**Second question**: why did this behavior regarding the built-in functions of GCC change so much between 2003 (when the book was written) and now? (Practically invalidating the whole example, it seems to me)

**Third question**: why does the author make his examples  (e.g.`$ gcc -Wall calc.c -lm -o cal`) implying that the static library `libc.a` will be used, when in reality in Linux that syntax invokes the dynamic library `libm.so`? Is this specific to Linux and not to GNU GCC? What am I mising?

Comment: Because 15 years is **a lot** of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is due to optimization of a constant value. Modern GCC can compute exact value of `sqrt (2.0)`. If you force it not to use the built-ins with `-fno-builtin`, it will still fail to link. Also, if you change the code a little bit so that the argument to `sqrt()` is not literal, it will fail to link:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double t = 2.0;

int main (void)
{
    double x = sqrt (t);
    printf ("The square root of 2.0 is %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces link error:

```
> gcc -o test test.c              
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLjHnQx.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Regarding your 3rd question, `-lm` does not imply static library, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in 2003 the optimization of a constant value was not performed in GCC yet, right?    What do you think of my third (slightly unrelated) question? I'm curious...